# Is there are reason I select by a string columns which contains SHA1 hexdigests?

Tags: sql, sqlite, sqlite3-ruby

I have an invitations table which looks like this

```
sqlite> .schema invitations
CREATE TABLE "invitations" 
    ( "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL
    , "sender_id" integer
    , "recipient_email" varchar(255)
    , "token" varchar(255)
    , "sent_at" datetime
    , "team_id" integer
    , "created_at" datetime
    , "updated_at" datetime
    );

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "index_invitations_on_recipient_email_and_team_id"
    ON "invitations" ("recipient_email", "team_id");

CREATE INDEX "index_invitations_on_sender_id"
    ON "invitations" ("sender_id");

CREATE INDEX "index_invitations_on_team_id"
    ON "invitations" ("team_id");
```

The token column stores hexdigests which are generated on record create like so (Ruby):

```
self.token = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest([Time.now, rand].join)
```

When I insert an invitation into the database, I can retrieve it with

```
SELECT * FROM "invitations" where "invitations"."recipient_email" = "an email"
```

but

```
SELECT * FROM "invitations" where "invitations"."token" = "an token"
```

returns noting even though I'm copy/pasting the exact token from the insert statement?

**Edit**
It turns out that

```
SELECT * FROM "invitations" where "invitations"."token" LIKE "an token"
```

will retrive the record correctly.

Why would "LIKE" work, but "=" not? I've tried stripping the hex before insert and doing a case insensitive select. Neither worked.

**Edit 2**
It seems I'm able to replicate this issue using only the rubygem "sqlite3" and the command line. That is without Rails etc.

Here's the process:

```
stuff $ gem install sqlite3
Fetching: sqlite3-1.3.3.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed sqlite3-1.3.3
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for sqlite3-1.3.3...
Installing RDoc documentation for sqlite3-1.3.3...
stuff $ irb
ruby-1.9.2-head :001 > require "sqlite3"
ruby-1.9.2-head :017 > rows = db.execute <<-SQL
ruby-1.9.2-head :018"> create table invitations (
ruby-1.9.2-head :019"> token varchar(40)
ruby-1.9.2-head :020"> );
ruby-1.9.2-head :021"> SQL
# with normal strings for comparison
ruby-1.9.2-head :022 > ['4535435', 'jfeu833'].each {|hash| db.execute "insert into 'invitations' ('token') values (?)", hash }
 => ["4535435", "jfeu833"] 
ruby-1.9.2-head :023 > db.execute("select * from invitations where invitations.token = '4535435'") {|row| p row }
# it finds the row successfully
["4535435"]
 => #<SQLite3::Statement:0x000001011741c8> 
ruby-1.9.2-head :028 > require "digest/sha1"
 => true 
# now to try it with a hash
ruby-1.9.2-head :029 > [Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("banana")].each {|hash| db.execute "insert into 'invitations' ('token') values (?)", hash }
 => ["250e77f12a5ab6972a0895d290c4792f0a326ea8"]
ruby-1.9.2-head :031 > db.execute("select * from invitations where invitations.token = '250e77f12a5ab6972a0895d290c4792f0a326ea8'") {|row| p row }
# notice that no record is printed
 => #<SQLite3::Statement:0x0000010107c630>
```

Comment: I edited the post with the schema. Let me know if you'd like to see anything else.

Comment: Yep. `select "token" from "invitations"` gets me a token correctly -> `e8c6ab9d5d1df98c906952c58e1be4d640d3c5ae`. Copy pasting that into a select like so: `select * from "invitations" where "invitations"."token" = "e8c6ab9d5d1df98c906952c58e1be4d640d3c5ae";` returns nothing.

Comment: Ok now I got something. When I do `insert into "invitations" ("recipient_email", "token") values ("fred","e8c6ab9d5d1df98c906952c58e1be3d640d3c5a7");` and then retrieve like `select * from "invitations" where "invitations"."token" = "e8c6ab9d5d1df98c906952c58e1be3d640d3c5a7";` I get the record out. So there must be something going wrong with my inserts (which were done within the Ruby on Rails environment). But what?

Comment: @muistooshort let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1397/discussion-between-duckyfuzz-and-mu-is-too-short)

Comment: @duckyfuzz: Can you try with `WHERE invitations.token = '250e...'
 COLLATE RTRIM` ?

Comment: @ypercube: Here's the query I ran -> `SELECT * FROM invitations WHERE invitations.token = '03ae5376b6a590840ebe9b138999133debbdc5c1' COLLATE RTRIM;`. It returns nothing. To show the record really is there: `SELECT * FROM invitations WHERE invitations.recipient_email = 'bob@email.com' COLLATE RTRIM;` returns `1|1|bob@email.com|03ae5376b6a590840ebe9b138999133debbdc5c1||1|2011-07-13 12:23:42.111740|2011-07-13 12:23:42.111740`. Those tokens should match fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I discussed this with the duckyfuzz (the OP) in a chat, and we found that the hash is stored as a BLOB in sqlite:

```
sqlite> select typeof(token) from invitations; 
blob 
blob
```

So for some reason, even though ruby says that what is being inserted is a string:

```
irb(main):002:0> (Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("banana")).class() 
=> String
```

it ends up in sqlite as a BLOB.

Interpolating the value, or inserting as literal, instead of inserting using parameters makes the problem go away (as tested by the OP):

```
oh ok got it
ruby-1.9.2-head :010 > db.execute("insert into invitations (token) VALUES ('#{the_hash}')") 
=> []
ok now the dump..

INSERT INTO "invitations" VALUES('bda04628ea94f26cac0793eac103258eb515c505');
much better!
```

The issue is caused by the fact that [binary strings will be stored as blobs](https://groups.google.com/group/sqlite3-ruby/browse_thread/thread/e341a69e650b3824?hl=en) by the sqlite3 rubygem. The way to prevent this is to encode the hash as UTF-8 before insert.

```
hash = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("banana").encode("UTF-8")
db.execute("insert into invitations (token) values (?)", hash)
```

Once you do that, the hash will be stored as text.

Comment: Hehe I kinda have to assume that something of the sort is happening here, but I don't know ruby so my ability to verify this is limited.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I would waste a day without it :)

Answer (score 0):

Changing `token` from `varchar(255)` to `char(40)` may help.

---

One other thing that bugs me is that you use double quotes: `"`

I've always thought that

```
select *
from "invitations" 
where "invitations"."token" = "e8c6ab9d5d1df98c906952c58e1be4d640d3c5ae"
```

is different than:

```
select *
from 'invitations' 
where 'invitations'.'token' = 'e8c6ab9d5d1df98c906952c58e1be4d640d3c5ae'
```

and different than:

```
select *
from `invitations` 
where `invitations`.token` = `e8c6ab9d5d1df98c906952c58e1be4d640d3c5ae`
```

Not at all sure how Rails and SQLite behaves on this matter. I'm always using (in MySQL and SQL-Server):

```
select *
from invitations 
where invitations.token = 'e8c6ab9d5d1df98c906952c58e1be4d640d3c5ae'
```

Comment: Nope. Doesn't seem to have worked. Thanks for the suggestion anyway.

Comment: @duckyfuzz: I installed ruby, rubygem-sqlite3, and yet I can't seem to load sqlite3 via "require 'sqlite3'"; any idea what else I need to do to use sqlite3? (on Fedora 15)

Comment: @sixfeetsix: I just guessed it may be some kind of strange behaviour (or conversion) to varchar(255) before the equality check. He needs only 40 chars anyway, doesn't he?

Comment: @ypercube: Not sure about any overhead of having >40 in the column definition caused by ruby's sqlite3 module, but as far as sqlite only is concerned, it changes nothing; to make this stand-out I only use TEXT in my table definitions.

Comment: @sixfeetsix Once you install the 'sqlite3' gem via `gem install sqlite3` you should be good to go. Try opening a ruby interactive console session by typing `irb` in the folder you installed the sqlite3 gem (i dunno if you installed it globally or not). In `irb`, `require "sqlite3"` should return `=> true` and then you can run sqlite stuff. https://github.com/luislavena/sqlite3-ruby for more info

Comment: @duckyfuzz: any chance you can link a db with that strange token?

Comment: @sixfeetsix I added complete steps to replicate the problem with the `sqlite3` rubygem. I'll see if I can put a sample DB up somewhere and link it.

Comment: @duckyfuzz: I must really suck with this ruby/gem/install/require stuff, please see the chat for what I did and see if you can tell me where things go awry...